# Detecting if a client is using IPv6 using SSI (Apache 2.4.7)

Tags: apache, ipv6, ssi

I'm trying to use SSI to detect if a client is using IPv6. The Apache documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) says there should be a variable called "IPV6" that I should be able to call, but when I try to call it using SSI the server returns (none).

I've confirmed that IPV6 isn't an active variable using the `<!--#printenv -->` command in my SHTML page.

I can use the REMOTE_ADDR variable to return the IP address of the client, so I thought I would try using RegEx to the REMOTE_ADDR variable with an IPv6 address format.

However, when I try the server returns [an error occurred while processing this directive].

I haven't worked with SSI much before, so this one has me a bit stumped. I've pasted with I have tried below:

```
<!--#if expr="$REMOTE_ADDR = /(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))/" -->
IPv6
<!--#elseif -->
IPv4
<!--#endif -->
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The syntax for regexp matches is `string =~ /regexp/`. Notice the tilde after the equals sign.

Comment: Hm, I've tried but it is still returning the same error  [an error occurred while processing this directive].